# Generating a print and a print preview report

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I am developing a report at the moment and I want to apply OOP principle because I feel like my code is not well written and there is duplication.

I have a method that gets data from the database and binds it to the controls on my report.

Here is a sample method I used to print preview a report:

```
public static void CreateReportResult(string poNumber)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("PurchaseOrders");
    Dal.GetDataSet(ds, sqlQuery(poNumber));
    PurchaseReport purchaseOrderReport = new PurchaseReport
    {
        DataSource = ds,
        DataMember = "PurchaseOrders"
    };


    purchaseOrderReport.xrDateCreated.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.DateCreated", "{0:dddd, d MMMM, yyyy}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrPO.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PONumber", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrVendor.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.POVendor", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrPromocode.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PromoCode", "{0}");
    //Bill Group
    //purchaseOrderReport.xrBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_BillToGroup", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress1.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine1", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress2.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine2", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CityStateZip", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_Phone", "{0}");
    //Customer
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerBusinessName", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerName", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.customerAddress", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerCityStateZip", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerPhone", "{0}");
    //Items
    purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell4.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.ModelNumber", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell5.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Quantity", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell8.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Price", "{0}");
    purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell6.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Description", "{0}");
    //LiftGate
    //   purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.LiftGate", "{0}");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Dal.GetDataTable(dt, "SELECT TOP 1  LiftGate, UPSAccount, LocalPickUp from Purchase_Order where  PONumber='" + poNumber + "'");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)row["UPSAccount"])
        {
            purchaseOrderReport.xrUPS.Visible = true;
        }
        if ((bool)row["LocalPickUp"])
        {
            purchaseOrderReport.xrPickedUp.Visible = true;
        }
        if ((bool)row["LiftGate"])
        {
            purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "NO";
        }
    }
    ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(purchaseOrderReport);
    printTool.ShowRibbonPreview();   //Preview a Report
}
```

Down here at the bottom of the code is the actual code use to print preview the report. I also have another method same as the one above but its function is to print the report.

The problem with my code is when I need to change something I need to change it on my print method as well which breaks the law of OOP. Anyone here who's willing to guide me write this one into a better, more maintainable piece of code.

By the way, this is the code for my Print method

```
  public static void PrintPDF(string poNumber)
    {
        #region PrintPDF

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("PurchaseOrders");
        Dal.GetDataSet(ds, sqlQuery(poNumber));
        PurchaseReport purchaseOrderReport = new PurchaseReport
        {
            DataSource = ds,
            DataMember = "PurchaseOrders"
        };

        purchaseOrderReport.xrDateCreated.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.DateCreated",
            "{0:dddd, d MMMM, yyyy}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrPO.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PONumber", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrVendor.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.POVendor", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrPromocode.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PromoCode", "{0}");
        //Bill Group
        //purchaseOrderReport.xrBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_BillToGroup", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress1.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine1", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress2.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine2", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CityStateZip", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_Phone", "{0}");
        //Customer
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null,
            "PurchaseOrders.CustomerBusinessName", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerName", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.customerAddress", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null,
            "PurchaseOrders.CustomerCityStateZip", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerPhone", "{0}");
        //Items
        purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell4.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.ModelNumber", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell5.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Quantity", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell8.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Price", "{0}");
        purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell6.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Description", "{0}");
        //LiftGate
        //   purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.LiftGate", "{0}");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Dal.GetDataTable(dt,
            "SELECT TOP 1  LiftGate, UPSAccount, LocalPickUp from Purchase_Order where  PONumber='" + poNumber + "'");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool) row["UPSAccount"])
            {
                purchaseOrderReport.xrUPS.Visible = true;
            }
            if ((bool) row["LocalPickUp"])
            {
                purchaseOrderReport.xrPickedUp.Visible = true;
            }
            if ((bool) row["LiftGate"])
            {
                purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "YES";
            }
            else
            {
                purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "NO";
            }
        }
        ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(purchaseOrderReport);
        printTool.Print();

        #endregion
    }
```

And this is my code for the querying the database to get the data..

```
 private static string sqlQuery(string poNumber)
    {
        string sql= @"SELECT  a.POVendor ,
                        a.PONumber ,
                        a.DateCreated ,
                        a.PromoCode ,
                        a.CustomerBusinessName ,
                        a.CustomerName ,                           
                        CONCAT(a.CustomerAddress1, ' ', a.CustomerAddress2) AS customerAddress,
                        CONCAT(a.CustomerCity, ' ', a.CustomerState, ' ', a.CustomerZip) AS CustomerCityStateZip,                          
                        a.CustomerPhone ,
                        a.b_BillToGroup ,
                        a.b_AddressLine1 ,
                        a.b_AddressLine2 ,
                        a.b_City, 
                        a.b_State,
                        a.b_Zip,
                        CONCAT(a.b_City, ' ', a.b_State, ' ', a.b_Zip) as CityStateZip ,
                        a.b_Phone ,
                        b.ModelNumber ,
                        b.Quantity ,
                        b.Description,
                        '$' + Cast(b.Price as varchar(10)) as Price
                FROM    PURCHASE_ORDER a
                        INNER JOIN PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS b ON a.PONumber = b.PurchaseOrderItems                            
                WHERE   a.PONumber='" + poNumber + "'";
        return sql;
    }
```

This report is created using DevExpress Report, just in case you need other information.

Comment: If the `poNumber` in your code is user-provided I'd like to suggest you use a prepared statement. In the case of MySQL it would be something like `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE a.PONumber = ?poNumber", connection); cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?poNumber", poNumber);`

Comment: Thanks for the concern but my poNumber is not user-provided..

Comment: @Derstine even if you're not worried about injection, it's worthwhile to use a prepared statement for the performance benefits. Idk about MySQL, but older versions of SQL Server would generate a new query plan for each `poNumber` it ever gets passed. Prepared statements allow it to use the plan cache instead.

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks for the input. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Only the most evident flaws ...

1. Very probably your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks ...
2. If you want OOP suggestions then i could say that [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) is violated. Your method `CreateReportResult` (not even a class, but a method) does a few things - retrieve data from database and create report. So move this logic into DAL `"SELECT TOP 1  LiftGate, UPSAccount, LocalPickUp from Purchase_Order where  PONumber='" + poNumber + "'");`
3. Move duplicated code into separate method (as you mentioned for new requests\improvements you have to change code in 2 methods). Like this

   ```
   public static void CreateReportResult(string poNumber)
   {
       var printTool = GetReportPrintTool();
       printTool.ShowRibbonPreview();   //Preview a Report
   }
   public static void PrintPDF(string poNumber)
   {
       ReportPrintTool printTool = GetReportPrintTool();
       printTool.Print();
   }

   public static ReportPrintTool GetReportPrintTool()
   {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet("PurchaseOrders");
       Dal.GetDataSet(ds, sqlQuery(poNumber));
       PurchaseReport purchaseOrderReport = new PurchaseReport
       {
           DataSource = ds,
           DataMember = "PurchaseOrders"
       };


       purchaseOrderReport.xrDateCreated.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.DateCreated", "{0:dddd, d MMMM, yyyy}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrPO.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PONumber", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrVendor.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.POVendor", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrPromocode.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.PromoCode", "{0}");
       //Bill Group
       //purchaseOrderReport.xrBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_BillToGroup", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress1.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine1", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrAddress2.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_AddressLine2", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CityStateZip", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.b_Phone", "{0}");
       //Customer
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerBusinessName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerBusinessName", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerName", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.customerAddress", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerCityStateZip.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerCityStateZip", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrCustomerPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.CustomerPhone", "{0}");
       //Items
       purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell4.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.ModelNumber", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell5.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Quantity", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell8.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Price", "{0}");
       purchaseOrderReport.xrTableCell6.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.Description", "{0}");
       //LiftGate
       //   purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "PurchaseOrders.LiftGate", "{0}");

       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       Dal.GetDataTable(dt, "SELECT TOP 1  LiftGate, UPSAccount, LocalPickUp from Purchase_Order where  PONumber='" + poNumber + "'");
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           if ((bool)row["UPSAccount"])
           {
               purchaseOrderReport.xrUPS.Visible = true;
           }
           if ((bool)row["LocalPickUp"])
           {
               purchaseOrderReport.xrPickedUp.Visible = true;
           }
           if ((bool)row["LiftGate"])
           {
               purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "YES";
           }
           else
           {
               purchaseOrderReport.xrLiftGate.Text = "NO";
           }
       }
       ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(purchaseOrderReport);

       return printTool;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to rewrite my code like you suggested.